# Eslint 'rxjs/operators' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: typescript, eslint, package.json

So i have this import on my file

```
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And when i run eslint i get this error:

```
 error  'rxjs/operators' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S rxjs/operators' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

I have rxjs in the package.json dependencies list, but it seems eslint thinks 'rxjs/operators' is another package instead.

In my eslintrc file, i have this rule:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
        "error",
        {
            "devDependencies": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.test.tsx"]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it following: [this](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#importcore-modules)
by adding

```
...
"settings": {
   "import/core-modules": ["rxjs/operators"]
},
...
```

in my *.eslintrc.json* config file.

Answer (score 2):

@Wana's solution works, but you may find that this was in fact an issue with the eslint-plugin-import rule.

If you update `eslint-plugin-import` to v2.23.4, you may find this is fixed. There was a recent regression in the package resolution algorithm.

```sh
npm update eslint-plugin-import
```

[Read more about the issue](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/2097)